# create two-way table value with data R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 groups and values, and I would like to have a two way table with Values, but with the function "table" I only have the number of occurrences as values.
Example :

I have a dataframe like this :

```
 GroupA   GroupB   Value
 A1       B1       4
 A1       B2       3
 A2       B1       2
 A1       B1       3
```

And I would like a table like this :

```
    A1     A2
B1  7      2
B2  3      0
```

(Since there is no data for A2 B2, it is 0)

Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `xtabs` for this

```
xtabs(Value~GroupB + GroupA, df)

#       GroupA
#GroupB  A1 A2
#  B1     7  2
#  B2     3  0
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr-tidyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
group_by(GroupA, GroupB) %>% 
summarise(Value=sum(Value)) %>% 
spread(GroupA, Value, fill=0)  
#      GroupB    A1    A2
#       (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)
#    1     B1     7     2
#    2     B2     3     0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df1, GroupB~GroupA, sum)
#   A1 A2
#B1  7  2
#B2  3  0
```

---

Or a `base R` option is `tapply`

```
tapply(df1$Value, df1[2:1], sum)
```